# Override img class in gallery

Tags: images, css, gallery

I use Wordpress for AngularJS as backend (wp-json plugin ) and actually what I made as structure for the theme looks like

```
myApptheme
  -style.css //nothing special here just inits the theme
  -index.php
  -header.php
  -functions.php
  lib //here some overrides php
  --gallery.php
  app //holds the angular stuff generated with yo angular
  bower_components //bower packages what I need
```

and in gallery.php(this one I borrowed from roots with own changes ) I add masonry needed markup and I try to filter my gallery items and add custom class (img-responsive) for bootstrap. The snippet looks as it follows.

```
/**
 * Add class="img-responsive" to attachment items
 */


function responsive_attachment_link_class($html) {

   $classes = 'img-responsive'; // separated by spaces, e.g. 'img image-link'

  // check if there are already classes assigned to the anchor
  if ( preg_match('/<img.*? class="/', $html) ) {
    $html = preg_replace('/(<img.*? class=" .*?)(".*?\="">)/', '$1 ' . $classes . ' $2', $html);
  } else {
    $html = preg_replace('/(<img.*?)(\>)/', '$1 class="' . $classes . '" $2', $html);
  }
  // remove dimensions from images,, does not need it!
  $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
  return $html;
}

add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'responsive_attachment_link_class');
```

removing `img width|heigh`t  works but not the class override. What is wrong with this codes?

**actual output**

```
<img alt="ind018" class="attachment-large" src="http://wp.local/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/ind018-728x1024.jpeg">
```

**expected**

```
<img alt="ind018" class="img-responsive" src="http://wp.local/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/ind018-728x1024.jpeg">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `!important` to your styles in order to override it. Better way to do this is to copy the `.img-responsive` styles from the Bootstrap CSS file and apply these styles to your desired HTML element instead of adding a class using PHP.

```
img.attachment-large {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Or target the element by the parent element if the class is not constant.

OR use [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_image_tag_class) filter.

```
function my_image_class_filter( $classes ) {
    return $classes.' attachment-large';
}
add_filter( 'get_image_tag_class', 'my_image_class_filter' );`
```

Comment: look at the update. You can not achieve from css. First you need the class to do css manipulations

Comment: @fefe see my updated answer.

Comment: `!important` is really not the best way to override. If you properly enqueue stylesheets this won't be necessary

Comment: another update what I made

Comment: @PieterGoosen you're right but if he has inline styles like width or height he probably needs to add !important to max-width and height css properties.